# How to assign the update the static member in a class in es6/js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is a simple operation, but it seems to be tricky.
so here is a simple class with a static method.

```
export class MyClass {
  static foo = {"key" : "value"};

  static bar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MyClass.foo));
  MyClass.bar["key"] = "newVal";
}
```

considering that foo is a very large object that wants to copy in another static variable `bar`. after coping I want to update some properties.

but this doesn't seem to work, getting error, `Unknown keyword or identifier. Did you mean 'class'?`

`MyClass.bar["key"] = "newVal";` this is invalid.

what's the issue here? how to update the static member just after assigning.

Comment: The syntax is OK, but you can't have an expression floating around in the middle of your `class` declaration; it has to be in some method.

Comment: _"so here is a simple class with a static method."_ - There's no method in your class.

Comment: How about `static bar = Object.assign(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MyClass.foo)), {key: 'newVal'})` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [a static initialisation block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_static_initialization_blocks):

```js
class MyClass {
  static foo = {"key" : "value"};

  static bar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MyClass.foo));
  static {
    MyClass.bar["key"] = "newVal";
  }
}
console.log(MyClass.foo);
console.log(MyClass.bar);
```

Or do the whole initialisation in the static block:

```js
class MyClass {
  static foo = {"key" : "value"};

  static {
    //`this` in a static block refers to the class
    this.bar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MyClass.foo));
    this.bar["key"] = "newVal";
  }
}
console.log(MyClass.foo);
console.log(MyClass.bar);
```

An alternative would be [an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) for environments that do not support static blocks:

```js
class MyClass {
  static foo = {"key" : "value"};

  static bar = (() => {
    const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MyClass.foo));
    obj["key"] = "newVal";
    return obj;
  })();
}
console.log(MyClass.foo);
console.log(MyClass.bar);
```

Or just put the update after the class declaration:

```js
class MyClass {
  static foo = {"key" : "value"};
  static bar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MyClass.foo));
}
MyClass.bar["key"] = "newVal";
console.log(MyClass.foo);
console.log(MyClass.bar);
```

Comment: could we do this :- ?
     class MyClass {
       static foo = {"key" : "value"};

      static {
     bar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MyClass.foo));
    MyClass.bar["key"] = "newVal";
  }
}

Comment: just removed one static block,

Comment: @rahulKushwaha no, that will attempt to assign to an implicit global called `bar` and would fail because the code is executed in strict mode. I have added a solution that will work - it is the second code block now.

Comment: just curious, so would this also not work,?

static {MyClass.bar = SON.parse(JSON.stringify(MyClass.foo));}

Comment: @rahulKushwaha That would work, since it's assigning to a property of an object `bar = /* ... */` will fail because it's *not* assigning a property but an implicit global variable. Which is an error in strict mode.